# Showing a char * buffer as an image

Tags: char, c++-cli, picturebox

I receive a JPEG image from a sever in a `char *` buffer. I want to show this picture in a picture box before saving it.All I know is that a picture box can show images from File, Hbitmap and Stream. I don't want to use the file one. and I don't know how to use the other ones.

I've searched and tried some, And here's my code. 
I don't know why it doesn't show any picture.

```
delegate void setImagedelegate(Stream ^ image);
void threadDecodeAndShow()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            if (f)
            {

                //the package that is receiving has some custom headers,
                // I first find about the size of the JPEG and 
                //put a pointer at the beginning of the JPEG part.  

                BYTE *pImgSur = NULL;
                DWORD imageInfoLength = *(DWORD*)m_pImgDataBufPtr[nIndexCurBuf];
                DWORD customInfoLenForUser = *(DWORD*)(m_pImgDataBufPtr[nIndexCurBuf] + 4 + imageInfoLength);
                DWORD jpegLength = *(DWORD*)(m_pImgDataBufPtr[nIndexCurBuf] + 4 + imageInfoLength + 4 + customInfoLenForUser);
                pImgSur = (BYTE *)(m_pImgDataBufPtr[nIndexCurBuf] + 12 + customInfoLenForUser + imageInfoLength);

                auto store = gcnew array<Byte>(jpegLength);
                System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(IntPtr(pImgSur), store, 0, jpegLength);
                auto stream = gcnew System::IO::MemoryStream(store);

                this->setImage(stream);

                f = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    void setImage(Stream ^ image)
    {
        if (this->pictureBox1->InvokeRequired)
        {
            setImagedelegate^ d =
                gcnew setImagedelegate(this, &MainPage::setImage);
            this->Invoke(d, gcnew array<Object^> { image });
        }
        else
        {

            this->pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromStream(image);
            this->pictureBox1->Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a char* buffer into a stream with a memory stream.  Two ways to do it, depends on how long the buffer remains valid.  The Image class requires the backing store for the stream to remain readable for the life of the image.  So if you are 100% sure that you can rely on the buffer surviving long enough then you can do it like this:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;

Image^ BytesToImage(char* buffer, size_t len) {
    auto stream = gcnew System::IO::UnmanagedMemoryStream((unsigned char*)buffer, len);
    return Image::FromStream(stream);
}
```

If you don't have that guarantee, or you can't be sure, then you have to copy the buffer content:

```
Image^ BytesToImageBuffered(char* buffer, size_t len) {
    auto store = gcnew array<Byte>(len);
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(IntPtr(buffer), store, 0, len);
    auto stream = gcnew System::IO::MemoryStream(store);
    return Image::FromStream(stream);
}
```

The garbage collector takes care of destroying the stream and array objects, happens after you dispose the Image object, so no need to help.

Comment: thank you for answering , after trying a lot of things your solution works without errors but it doesn't show any images.

Comment: Hmm, this code is not supposed to "show any images", it merely converts bytes.  I could not possibly guess, you'll have to ask another question and properly document what you do with the returned Image object.

Comment: I edited my post and added the code. can you please take look at it?

Comment: Hmm, the odds that pImgSur is a valid pointer look very low.  Just a guess without knowing what the custom header looks like and how m_pImageDataBufPtr is declared.  Ask a team member to help you.